# Use a client certificate in a WebJob

Tags: c#, azure, ssl, azure-webjobs

I have a web job running on an Azure web app. I web job needs to access a client certificate for outbound traffic encryption.

How can I access a client certificate from an Azure web job? 
I tried installing the certificate on the host web app and access the certificate this way:

```
    private static X509Certificate2 LoadCertificateFromStore(string certificateThumbprint){
        var store = new X509Store(StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        try {
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
            var certCollection = store.Certificates;
            var currentCertificate = certCollection.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, certificateThumbprint, false);
            if (currentCertificate.Count == 0)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Could not find certificate " + certificateThumbprint);
            return currentCertificate[0];
        } finally{
            store.Close();
        }
    }
```

This unfortunately didn't work as the certificate could not be found. 
I am stuck.

Comment: you can find a similar answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39305213/4167200

Comment: Possible duplicate of [X509CertificateCollection problems in an Azure webjob](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39287397/x509certificatecollection-problems-in-an-azure-webjob)

Comment: Oh thanks for the pointer. I am marking mine as a duplicate then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oh got it! I followed all the steps [in this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/nb-no/blog/using-certificates-in-azure-websites-applications/) but I missed an important step: You must add a setting named "WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES" to the web app "APP SETTINGS" which will force the web app to load all certificates.

Comment: @AllanXu Thanks for the reminder, forgot to mark this as an Answer :)