# Azure Web Job not able to establish SSL/TLS connection with client certificate

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-webjobs

Hi I've a WebJob which needs to communicate with an external Web Service using HTTPS and a client certificate, but I get (only on Azure) this error:**Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority 'wstest.agenziadoganemonopoli.gov.it'.The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.**

*wstest.agenziadoganemonopoli.gov.it* supports only TLS 1.2 ([SSLLabs test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=wstest.agenziadoganemonopoli.gov.it)) and I've already added

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, errors) => true;
```

*wstest.agenziadoganemonopoli.gov.it* requires a different client certificate per user, so I load the right certificate from a blob.

I didn't use **WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES** as suggested here [Use a client certificate in a WebJob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41707325/use-a-client-certificate-in-a-webjob) mainly because I load the certificate from an external store (Azure Blob Storage) and I have a different certificate per user (I have >1000 certificates to manage).

**UPDATE**
This is (more or less) the code I use to load the certificate from Azure Blob Storage

```
    public async Task<Result<X509Certificate2>> GetCertificate(Guid merchantId)
    {
        try
        {
            CloudBlobContainer container =
                _client.GetContainerReference($"{ContainerNamePrefix}-{merchantId.ToString().ToLower()}");

            CloudBlockBlob certificateBlobBlock = container.GetBlockBlobReference(CertificateBlobBlockName);

            CloudBlockBlob metadataBlobBlock = container.GetBlockBlobReference(MetadataBlobBlockName);

            AuthenticationCertificateMetadata metadata =
                JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AuthenticationCertificateMetadata>(
                    await metadataBlobBlock.DownloadTextAsync().ConfigureAwait(false));

            X509Certificate2 certificate = null;

            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                await certificateBlobBlock.DownloadToStreamAsync(stream).ConfigureAwait(false);

                certificate = new X509Certificate2(stream.ToArray(), metadata.CertificatePassword);
            }

            return Result<X509Certificate2>.Successful(certificate);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Any suggestion?

Thanks!
Federico

Comment: How do you get certificate and use it? Can you share any pieces of code?

Comment: Who is the issuer of the client certificate? Not sure but you should have the full chain of trust on the calling machine (webjob server in your case).

Comment: @FabrizioAccatino I've added the code I use to load the certificate. The certificate is issued from some kind of italian CA, but I guess Microsoft does not support it :) Btw I guess using `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, errors) => true;` it should not matter if the certificate is valid or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I didn't use WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES as suggested

Actually, you **need to set the WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES in application setting**. This is required to load the client certificates for application.
[image]

> I load the certificate from an external store (Azure Blob Storage) and I have a different certificate per user

You could load a **certificate file** that is in your application directory, so that you could achieve a different client certificate per user.

For example:

```
 string certPath = Server.MapPath("~/certs/mycert.pfx");
 X509Certificate2 cert = GetCertificate(certPath, signatureBlob.Thumbprint);
```

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-ssl-cert-load).

Comment: So as you are saying I don't need to set **WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES** when loading it from a file, right? I need to set **WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES** only when I'm trying to load a certificate from the certificate store. So, seeing that I'm loading it from Azure Storage, I don't really need to set flag.

Comment: Both of them you need to add it. Because adding an app setting named WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES with its value set to the thumbprint of the certificate will make it accessible to your web application.

Comment: Thanks @JoeyCai, we were getting the `Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel` exception when loading a client certificate from a file, and adding the `WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES` setting fixed it

Comment: Glad to hear that! Cheer up:)